# How to Copy Text from Any Screen on Android

Tags: android, text, screen, capture

Selecting text on a touchscreen device has always been a major pain point. Those tiny little arrows that let you adjust the selection area are always too hard to actually adjust, making precision all but impossible.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please be more specific and do mention the failed solutions you tried and read on the above link☝

Answer (score 0):

Use public static variable like you want to get the text. Initialize Textview like this:

```
public static TextView yourtext;
```

and access like

```
String text= YourActvity.yourtext;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities to get other App's text: (1) do a screenshot and run an OCR procedure that extracts words from pixels (the accuracy could suffer a bit) or (2) on a Rooted device install Xposed Framework and write an Xposed Module that allows to select all displayed text by changing the normal behavior of all components (not focusable TextViews become focusable, etc..)